# Swift: App crashes when using UILongPressGestureRecognizer after switching views

Tags: swift, view, crash, switch-statement, gesture

In my view I have included two different UIGestureRecognizers, UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UITapGestureRecognizer. One is for rearranging my UICollectionView of images and the other one is for a simple tap, leading to a detailed view of the selected image.

Everything works at first, but as soon as I return to the view after having presented the detailed image view, the app crashes whenever I try to drag an image. The tapping function works every time, but it is immediately after starting dragging the image the crash occurs.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.longPressGesture = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleLongGesture(gesture:)))
    self.longPressGesture.delegate = self

    self.tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.handleTapGesture(gesture:)))
    self.tapGesture.delegate = self

    collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(self.longPressGesture)
    collectionView?.addGestureRecognizer(self.tapGesture)
}
```

My tap function:

```
@objc func handleTapGesture(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "displayImage", sender: self)
}
```

And my long press-function:

```
@objc func handleLongGesture(gesture: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    switch(gesture.state) {
    case .began:
        print("begin hold!")
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView?.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        self.collectionView?.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
    case .changed:
        print("change hold!")
        self.collectionView?.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: gesture.view!))
    case .ended:
        print("end hold!")
        UIView.performWithoutAnimation {
            self.collectionView?.endInteractiveMovement()
        }
    default:
        print("cancel hold!")
        self.collectionView?.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
}
```

When crashing, I get

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
>   NSException

This seems to happen in the .changed-case embedded in func handleLongGesture().

Any ideas? It would be much appreciated.

Comment: Adding a gesture to collection view doesn't sound like a good idea.  Besides, you don't even show how you call call handleLongGesture from your collection view.

Comment: It seems to be a standard way of handling rearrangements of collection view cells using UILongPressGestureRecognizer. The reason for using UITapGestureRecognizer is due to conflicts between UILongPressGestureRecognizer and UICollectionViewCell didSelectItemAtIndexPath. The function calls are made from having included the gesture recognizers in the collection view, which is done in viewDidLoad().

Answer (score 1):

After struggling with this for a few hours too long, I finally found out what was causing the problem. It had nothing to do with the gestures but with the collection view and its data. In viewWillAppear(), I update the view by re-adding the thumbnails to an array:

```
self.thumbnails.removeAll()
    for i in 0 ..< self.images.count {
        ... adding new (updating) thumbnails ...
}
```

But for some reason, I had forgotten to call thumbnails.removeAll(), causing the data to be duplicated whilst not calling reloadData() on the collection view, causing it to crash.